# Split from a specific character T - SQL

Tags: t-sql, split

I have a table with column `Country_City` which include a combinations of Countries and Cities separate with `:`, example `Egypt: Cairo` and i want to split them in 2 different columns, Country & City.

I manage to fulfill this task with `SUBSTRING` & `CHARINDEX` functions but i m searching for another solution if any.

Any opinions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a STRING_SPLIT function in SQL Server, but I don't think it will be better in your case, because the order of the values is not guaranteed.  So you will end up mixing cities and countries.

Comment: What's the reason? Why you want a different solution? That might be important to know.

Comment: There is not a particular reason. i was curious to know if there any function which gives the answer straight away.

Comment: you can use string_split with some pivot however when you dont know the order or dont have any other info this is a bit overkill contra substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches, but - to be honest - only one good choice: You should **never ever** store these values in one single column.

If you have to stick with this (legacy issue) or if you need this code in order to clean this bad structure, you may check one of these:

First a *mockup table* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Country_Region NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUEs('Egypt: Cairo'),('Germany: Berlin');
```

--Fastest in most cases will be this:

```
SELECT t.*
      ,TRIM(LEFT(t.Country_Region,A.PosColon-1)) AS Country
      ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(t.Country_Region,A.PosColon+1,1000)) AS Region
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(':',t.Country_Region) PosColon) A;
```

--Easy to read and good to use with more than two items per string (but rather slow)

```
SELECT t.*
      ,A.CastedToXml.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Country
      ,A.CastedToXml.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Region
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.Country_Region,': ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) CastedToXml) A;
```

--Needs v2016, but is very fast, easy to read and easy to up-scale

```
SELECT t.*
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.AsJSON,'$[0]') AS Country
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.AsJSON,'$[1]') AS Region
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONCAT('["',REPLACE(t.Country_Region,': ','","'),'"]') AsJSON) A;
```

All of them produce the same output

```
ID  Country_Region      Country     Region
1   Egypt: Cairo        Egypt       Cairo
2   Germany: Berlin     Germany     Berlin
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.